# What is the purpose of :: in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

I have seen double colons (`::`) in generated code. I was wondering what its purpose is?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's the [namespace alias qualifier operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx). Citing from the linked-to MSDN page:

> The namespace alias qualifier (`::`) is used to look up identifiers. It is always positioned between two identifiers, as in this example:
>
> ```
> global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
> ```

Comment: Note that it is actually not needed for any aliased name space, but only for the global. If you use any other alias, you can use the regular c# dot syntax (i.e. SomeAliasedAssembly.Namespace.Class.etc...)

Answer (score 41):

This is the namespace alias qualifier.  It's used when there's the potential for two different types with the same name and same namespace (coming from different assemblies).  E.g. our ORM product talks to VistaDB 3 and VistaDB 4.  In both cases the connection class is VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBConnection.  So we `extern alias` the VistaDB 3 assembly to `vdb3` and the VistaDB 4 assembly to `vdb4` and can now disambiguate the connection classes as `vdb3::VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBConnection` and `vdb4::VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBConnection`.  Without the alias qualifier, these would raise "ambiguous reference" compiler errors.

Comment: But can't you write `vdb3.VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBConnection` and `vdb4::VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBConnection` instead?

Comment: @AlexanderGonchiy: Yes, you could, but if you also had a *variable* with the name `vdb3`, then `vdb3.VistaDB` would try to access the `VistaDB` property of that variable. With `::`, the compiler knows that the left-hand side is *always* meant to be a namespace alias. But I agree, the need for this is rare.