# Import pic into array

Tags: c#, arrays, picturebox

I have _1.png, _2.png .... imported in resources files and I have created pictureBox1 in GUI interface.

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = global::IMPORT.Properties.Resources._1;
```

^ It is by far the only way for me to set image to _1

What if I wanna load _1.png, _2.png, ...., _10.png into array
and call that array according to the value

for example:

```
int[] arrr = { 0, 1, 2 };
int i = 2;
this.pictureBox1.Image = global::IMPORT.Properties.Resources.arr[i];
```

Is these kind of thoughts possible in C#?
I have searched for "pictureBox" and "Bitmap",
and I am totally lost, can someone please kindly help me ...

Comment: Is that actually C# or rather C++? The `::` look like the C++ scope operator to me.

Comment: @Codor We have it in  C# as well. It's called [namespace alias qualifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045052/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-c)

Comment: Use the ResourceManager.GetObject() method.  Like pictureBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" + arr[i].ToString());

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks for the explanation, I was totally unaware of it...

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comments, I will now work on your suggestions!! thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the feedbacks from @HansPassant,
the code of changing the image should be :

For example, I want to change boxImage to  "H13.png" imported in resources folder

```
int j = 13;

boxImage.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject( "H"+j.ToString() );
```

Thank you so much and I hope I can help beginner to understand how to change picture of C# !!!